# Putting includes in all the right places

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, header-files

So, we use `#include` to tell the compiler/linker where to find all the relevant code for a class.

Have a look at this:

```
ClassC.h:
    #include "ClassA.h";

ClassD.h:
    #include "ClassC.h"
```

Let's say we use `ClassA` in our `ClassD`, but in a way that is in no way connected to `ClassC`. We have implicitly included it by including `ClassC`, so no error is thrown. However, should the code change and `ClassC` is no longer needed (and we remove the `#include "ClassC.h"` because of that), we'd get undefined reference error since `ClassA` is now unreferenced.

Is there a way to have the compiler/linker look at each of the *.cpp and assigned *.h independently, without looking into included .h files?

If that were the case, it wouldn't look into `ClassC.h` and see it includes `ClassA.h`, but throw an error or at least a warning telling me that I didn't include `ClassA.h`. It makes more sense since, as far as class `ClassD` knows, `ClassA` and `ClassC` have no connection to one another (under the set assumption I'm using `ClassA` independently of `ClassC`).

I think that the code written that way would be much more stable and resilient to change. Wouldn't it?

Also, let's say we build a project, and it works. If we were to then reference some class(X) earlier in code than it was referenced before, we might get an error if it was using some other class(Y) that was included from some other source between that point in the program, and the previous first occurrence of that class. If we tied includes more closely to each header file that explicitly uses it, such errors would never appear.

I know I could keep track of all this myself, but it would be so easy to miss a few or more in larger projects, even medium ones. Besides, having an error/warning would make it so much easier to manage.

I know I'm complicating things a bit, but this seems a good practice to me.

It this even a good idea and can it somehow be set in compiler/linker options (e.g. GNU gcc compiler in CodeBlocks)?

Comment: You should check out include guards. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Include guards are great and prevent you to include same two things in a project, I know. I want to be able to include something in my code in 10 different places, if relevant, despite the compiler/linker using only the first one it gets to.

Comment: I neither understand what problem you are trying to solve nor the solution you are proposing

Comment: " want to be able to include something in my code in 10 different places" what prevents you from doing this?

Comment: I think the core of your problem is that you needlessly include headers into headers, rather than into the associated .cpp files. This may save some typing but also leads to one form of spaghetti.

Comment: If I don't put includes in header, the compiler can't understand the function definitions if they use them as arguments. But there are mostly forward declarations there, except for standard includes and external libraries. Besides, the problem remains even in cpp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say we use ClassA in our ClassD, but in a way that is in no way
>   connected to ClassC. We have implicitly included it by including
>   ClassC, so no error is thrown. However, should the code change and
>   ClassC is no longer needed (and we remove the #include "ClassC.h"
>   because of that), we'd get undefined reference error since ClassA is
>   now unreferenced.

If you need to use `ClassA` in your `ClassD`, then **explicitly** `#include "ClassA.h"` in your `ClassD.h`. Do *not* rely on *implicit* chains of inclusions.

Comment: I want to do that. I just want to know if there is a way for compiler to do the check for me.

Comment: @Karlovsky120: At this point I don't know what you exactly mean. The compiler doesn't have psychic powers to guess what headers you want. Anyway, if you don't include the required headers, you get compiler or linker errors.

Comment: I mainly meant if the compiler/linker can detect whether include was explicit or implicit and throw a warning in it was an implicit include. It might be hard to do since some implicit includes (e.g. ones inherited from parent class) would be fine since they'd always be present.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 So you mean like you're using class X but you don't directly include its header, and rely on implicit inclusion chains. I don't know if there is such tool available today.

Comment: I've done some research now and some static code analysers seems to check for that. I forgot which ones exactly.